# SQL current standard version

Tags: sql

Is SQL/2003 the latest standard version? I mean the SQL standard first adopted by ANSI in 1986.

I was told in 2011 they released a new one.

Sorry I do hope I won't be frowned upon.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization

Looks like in 2006, 2008, and 2011 were new standards since the 2003 one you speak of. Check the link for explanation as well as reference links.

Comment: So despite the effort to standardize the language there are several dialects..thanks a lot